# Unable to read csv in pandas with sys.argv[]

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I read a csv file in pandas by specifying the name directly. It works without trouble. But when I try to do the same with sys.argv[] it throws an error. This is what I tried.

```
import sys
import pandas as pd

filename = sys.argv[-1]

data = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter=',')
print data
print data[data['logFC'] >= 2]
```

The error it throws back is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/filter_cutoff_genexdata.py", line 7, in <module>
    data = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter=',')   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 498, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 285, in
_read
    return parser.read()   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 747, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1197, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)   File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 766, in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas/parser.c:7988)   File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 788, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas/parser.c:8244)   File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 842, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas/parser.c:8970)   File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 829, in pandas.parser.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas/parser.c:8838)   File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 1833, in pandas.parser.raise_parser_error (pandas/parser.c:22649) pandas.parser.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 7, saw 3
```

Can anyone please tell why it doesn't work ?

Comment: Your error is `C error: Expected 1 fields in line 7, saw 3`. There's a problem parsing the file. Also make sure you're loading the right file.

Comment: it's likely that your csv is not comma separated as the error is telling you that it's only expecting a single field, edit your post with a sample from your csv

Comment: When I do the same thing by removing filename = sys.argv[-1] line &  directly writing the filename, i.e data = pd.read_csv('file-to-be-read.csv', delimiter=',') it works perfectly fine !

Comment: add `print(filename)` before read_csv and make sure you do have the right one...

Comment: again the same error. I guess it is not even reading the filename !

Comment: Can you show how you're calling your code from the command line? If your `.csv` file has a space in its name you could only be getting the tail end of the filename in `sys.argv[-1]` and if you have another similarly named file you could be getting that one instead. Maybe try doing `print(sys.argv[-1]) `and see what you get?